# JSON decode failed in php

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to decode a json from my android application using php.But it returns a null string

Here is my code

```
$json="{account0Name: 'shamonsha665@gmail.com',account0Type: 'com.google',account1Name: 'mail.root5s@gmail.com',account1Type: 'com.google',account2Name: 'shamonwaste@gmail.com',account2Type: 'com.google',account3Name: '911.gksfapp@gmail.com',account3Type: 'com.google',account4Name: 'developer.root5@gmail.com',account4Type: 'com.google',account5Name: 'personal.root5@gmail.com',account5Type: 'com.google',account6Name: 'WhatsApp',account6Type: 'com.whatsapp',account7Name: 'shamonsha665@gmail.com',account7Type: 'com.linkedin.android',account8Name: '7736527089',account8Type: 'com.facebook.auth.login',deviceID: '911380450169267',phoneNo: '779808980',netCountry: 'in',netName: 'XXX',simNo: '8991197239007526600',simCountry: 'iX',simName: '!XX'}";

$owners=json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($owners);
```

`var_dump()` returns null value

Here is my json source

```
var deviceInfo = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/DeviceInformation");
    deviceInfo.get(function(result) {
    //get the plugin result 
     owner=JSON.stringify(result);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://ww.xxx.com/app/testjson.php',
        data:{'owner':owner},
        success: function(msg) {
          alert("from server"+msg);
        },
        error:function(err){
            alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err));
        }
      });
},, function() {
            console.log("error");
        });
```

Comment: use echo json_encode($json)

Comment: It returns the same string not the array

Comment: sorry i didnt understand you wanna print json right in php?

Comment: That isn't valid `json`, that's why. Check out [JSON Lint](http://www.jsonlint.com) where it will tell you how and why your `json` isn't valid.

Comment: oops my json is not in correct formatt

Comment: Why you want decode your json.

Comment: @Darren how can correct my json file its from my android app

Comment: Can you show how your android app is creating the json string and sending it?

Comment: Strings must be in **double quotes**. Single quotes are invalid. [Read the manual](http://json.org/). Also, use `json_last_error_msg()` to find out what the last error was. Read PHP's [JSON docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) if you have further problems.

Comment: i will get this from my json `Parse error on line 2:
[    {        account0Name: 'shamo
--------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'`

Comment: yea, i do with @SverriM.Olsen answer's.. replace your **single quote** to be **double quote**.

Comment: But its autogenerated json how can i manually add doubel quote

Comment: you can use str_replace function, ie. `$json = str_replace("'", '"', $json);`.

Comment: @root i have edited my answer can you check once...$json{..} changed..

Comment: you json is not valid.

Comment: @check  have done it but it shows only a part of string as double quoted`{account0Name: "shamonsha665@gmail.com"} ` `account0Name` cannot be double quoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this help.

```
<?php
$json="{account0Name: 'shamonsha665@gmail.com',account0Type: 'com.google',account1Name: 'mail.root5s@gmail.com',account1Type: 'com.google',account2Name: 'shamonwaste@gmail.com',account2Type: 'com.google',account3Name: '911.gksfapp@gmail.com',account3Type: 'com.google',account4Name: 'developer.root5@gmail.com',account4Type: 'com.google',account5Name: 'personal.root5@gmail.com',account5Type: 'com.google',account6Name: 'WhatsApp',account6Type: 'com.whatsapp',account7Name: 'shamonsha665@gmail.com',account7Type: 'com.linkedin.android',account8Name: '7736527089',account8Type: 'com.facebook.auth.login',deviceID: '911380450169267',phoneNo: '779808980',netCountry: 'in',netName: 'XXX',simNo: '8991197239007526600',simCountry: 'iX',simName: '!XX'}";

$json = str_replace(array("'", ': "', ',', '{'), array('"', '": "', ',"', '{"'), $json);

$owners = json_decode($json);
print_r($owners);

?>
```

**note: that's str_replace maybe not work correctly for another json.**

Update: Get Value

```
print_r($owners);
echo $owners->account0Name; // access object directly

$ownersArray = get_object_vars($owners); // convert to array
print_r($ownersArray);
echo $ownersArray['account0Name']; // and access by index
```

Comment: you can access object directly or use array by convert to array first. check on update answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Root its because you are decoding a json string that you have not encoded in the first place, so its decoding nothing. Try this:

```
`$json="{account0Name: 'shamonsha665@gmail.com',account0Type: 'com.google',account1Name: 'mail.root5s@gmail.com',account1Type: 'com.google',account2Name: 'shamonwaste@gmail.com',account2Type: 'com.google',account3Name: '911.gksfapp@gmail.com',account3Type: 'com.google',account4Name: 'developer.root5@gmail.com',account4Type: 'com.google',account5Name: 'personal.root5@gmail.com',account5Type: 'com.google',account6Name: 'WhatsApp',account6Type: 'com.whatsapp',account7Name: 'shamonsha665@gmail.com',account7Type: 'com.linkedin.android',account8Name: '7736527089',account8Type: 'com.facebook.auth.login',deviceID: '911380450169267',phoneNo: '779808980',netCountry: 'in',netName: 'XXX',simNo: '8991197239007526600',simCountry: 'iX',simName: '!XX'}";
$json = json_encode($json);

var_dump(json_decode($json));`
```

This totally works. 
`string(738) "{account0Name: 'shamonsha665@gmail.com',account0Type: 'com.google',account1Name: 'mail.root5s@gmail.com',account1Type: 'com.google',account2Name: 'shamonwaste@gmail.com',account2Type: 'com.google',account3Name: '911.gksfapp@gmail.com',account3Type: 'com.google',account4Name: 'developer.root5@gmail.com',account4Type: 'com.google',account5Name: 'personal.root5@gmail.com',account5Type: 'com.google',account6Name: 'WhatsApp',account6Type: 'com.whatsapp',account7Name: 'shamonsha665@gmail.com',account7Type: 'com.linkedin.android',account8Name: '7736527089',account8Type: 'com.facebook.auth.login',deviceID: '911380450169267',phoneNo: '779808980',netCountry: 'in',netName: 'XXX',simNo: '8991197239007526600',simCountry: 'iX',simName: '!XX'}"`

Comment: yeah thats worked.can you show how can i get each element from that array?

Comment: use this one  print_r(json_decode(stripslashes($json)));.

Comment: I use explode to get to each element.

Comment: like this buddy `$ser = json_decode($json);
$j = explode(',', $ser); 
?>
<pre><?php var_dump($j) ?></pre>`

Comment: output is like :::: `array(25) {
  [0]=>
  string(39) "{account0Name: 'shamonsha665@gmail.com'"
  [1]=>
  string(26) "account0Type: 'com.google'"
  [2]=>
  string(37) "account1Name: 'mail.root5s@gmail.com'"
  [3]=>
  string(26) "account1Type: 'com.google'"
  [4]=>
  string(37) "account2Name: 'shamonwaste@gmail.com'"
  string(15) "simName: '!XX'}"
}` I've removed some due to comment box length

Comment: JActually son file is auto generated so i will not able manully add double quotes to this .I use `str-replace()` function but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON isn't valid.

Should look like:

```
{"account0Name": "shamonsha665@gmail.com",...
```

and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Your Json String is wrong..can you change your json string as like below.

Try this code:-

```
   <?php
        $json='{"account0Name": "shamonsha665@gmail.com","account0Type": "com.google","account1Name": "mail.root5s@gmail.com",.........}';
        $obj = json_decode($json, true);
       print_r($obj);
    ?>
```

I think this is useful to your requirement.

Comment: Explain what you did.